# catkin_create_android_project error

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having some issue to create android packages for my stack.

Recently i had been playing with android apps for ROS and it worked fine.
As i reinstalled ubuntu yesterday, i fully reinstalled all packages

- ros-kinetic-desktop-full deb package
- android studio
- rosjava from source
- android_core from source

in my catkin_ws/src i execute the following commands

```
catkin_create_android_pkg p1_remote android_core rosjava_core std_msgs
catkin_create_android_project -t 25 -p lan.robonet.p1_remote.remote remote
```

Which results into:

```
~/Workspaces/ros/arduino_p1/src/p1_remote$ catkin_create_android_project -t 25 -p lan.robonet.p1_remote.remote remote

Creating android project 
  Name      : remote
  Target Ver: 25
  Java Name : lan.robonet.p1_remote.remote
  Activity  : Remote

Command: ['android', 'create', 'project', '-n', 'remote', '-p', '/home/randy/Workspaces/ros/arduino_p1/src/p1_remote/remote', '-k', 'lan.robonet.p1_remote.remote', '-t', 'android-25', '-a', 'Remote']
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
Error
[error] __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) : <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
```

Strange thing is that this worked before the reinstall. The only difference i see with previous install is that the Android SDK uses a newer sdk tools version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256041/catkin_create_android_project-error/) by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems this is related to the android sdk tool changes.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

The deprecated "android" command line tool has been removed :(
So it seems i need to switch back to an older sdk-tools version or update the rosjava/android_core sources to use the new command line tools

---

Originally posted by [RandyD](https://answers.ros.org/users/29157/randyd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0